# Is a global "current_utc_time" function in Rails a "bad" idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails program that has `Time.now.utc` sprinkled throughout the project in everything from controllers to models to specs. I like that it's expressive and you know exactly what's going on, but I'd also like to DRY it out so, ideally, `Time.now.utc` was only defined in one place.

My first thought is to create a new file and define a single unscoped function:

```
# /app/lib/current_utc_time.rb

def current_utc_time
  Time.now.utc
end
```

I'd need to make sure the file was required during boot, then replace every `Time.now.utc` with `current_utc_time`.

Anything wrong with this plan or are there better alternatives?

Comment: it's a good idea indeed. It'd be good to create a module/class where you handle common date/time operations for your app. That way it's centralized.

Comment: I think it's too objective but I don't think you are DRYing it. You are changing `Time.now.utc` with `current_utc_time` everywhere. I would understand if the function did something extra or you could have some special code you want to change everywhere at the same time, but you are just writing basically the same in another order.